# Adverbial numeral for the "teen"s

Tags: word-comparison, word-choice, numbers, mathematics

I noticed this numeral while reading *Regulus*, the Latin version of *the Little Prince*. In the scene that the businessman shows his sum of stars, he says:

> Cinq cent un millions six cent vingt-deux mille sept cent trente et un.

in the original French version and in the Latin it becomes

> Immo vero sunt **quinquies milies et sexies decies centena viginti duo milia stellarum septingentae triginta una stellae**.

The algebraic construction of this thread of numerals seems to be
`((5 × 1000 + (6 + 10)) × 100 + 20 + 2) × 1000 + 700 + 30 + 1 = ((5000 + 16) × 100 + 22)k + 731`, which is correctly as the French, `501,622,731`.

Here the Latin translator Haury uses **sexies decies** for "16×", which I felt a little weird. I consulted *Allen and Greenough's New Latin Grammar*, it gives a list a little irregular: "11×, 12×, 15×, 16×" are made by changing the cardinal **-decim** to **-decie(n)s**, whereas "13×, 14×, 17×" are a compound of **ter/quater/septies** and **decie(n)s**. However I found another [list](https://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/numeraliatab.htm) gives all of "13~17×" as "3~7×" + **decies**, without any citation.

Then I did a corpus search, and the result is shown below (**-ens** variations included):

> undecies 6 : semel decies 0
> duodecies 11 : bis d. 4 
> tredecies 0 : ter d. 6 (Lewis & Short's: "***trĕdĕcĭes** a false read. for **terdeciens**, Cic. Verr. 2, 3, 80, § 184.*")
> quattuordecies 0 : quater d. 2
> quindecies 7 : quinquies d. 0
> sedecies 9 : sexies d. 0
> septendecies 0 : septies d. 0 (**septiesdeciens** in A&G is unattested)

The result demonstrates an irregularity similar to what A&G tells, except for the "17×". Why are they like this? Why does A&G suggest **septiesdeciens** instead of **septendeciens** while both are unattested (at least in PHI Corpus)? Are there any later texts that illustrate the usage of these numerals? (I am especially curious about the scientific literatures in the New Latin period.)